# 2 Spring TransactionManager on the same datasource: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

i have a problem with a Spring TransactionManager. I have two JpaTransactionManager that insist on the same datasource. when I use the second transactionManager I take the error: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself.
How can I run both the transaction manager?

Comment: Why do you need 2 TransactionManager? You can open 2 transactions with one TransactionManager if you need

Comment: Why use a transaction manager for the application context and another for the ejb context to allow transactions to a ejb 3

Comment: Can't you create 2 different DataSources pointing the same DB

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know if there was another way without replicating ds